# Force Vim to only use 80 columns

Tags: environment-variables

I would like Vim (run in a terminal) to only use the leftmost 80 columns of the terminal (i.e., not display anything in the columns right of that). Of course, I don't want to have to resize my terminal window to 80 columns. How is it possible to achieve that?

I have tried:

- Setting `:set columns=80` in `vim`, but this has no effect
- Running `COLUMNS=80 vim`, but vim ignores the variable altogether
- Following `posix-screen-size` in help, putting `set cpoptions=aABceFs|` in my `.vimrc` and then retrying the above; but this has no effect either. I don't understand why -- `:help posix-screen-size` specifically promises that the `|` flag in `cpoptions` should make `vim` follow `LINES` and `COLUMNS` (see also `:help cpo-bar`).

To be precise, for the last point, because my shell (`zsh`) as a tendency to resetting `COLUMNS` to its default setting, I was careful to try in a separate shell. I tried what's below and it did not work:

```
$ export LINES=80 COLUMNS=80
$ echo $LINES $COLUMNS
80 80
$ vim -c 'set cpoptions+=|' path/to/file
```

I see that the `vimroom` plugin makes it possible to limit the number of columns used by vim (amongst other things), but doing this via such a plugin feels a bit overkill and also the plugin centers the display instead of using the leftmost columns which is not what I want.

How can I make `vim` use the leftmost 80 columns?

I'm happy with solutions that use, e.g., vsplits and additional panes (but provided they don't interfere with the editing, in particular, I would want `:q` to exit without having to close the useless panes); or alternatively using `tmux`...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is a very simple solution, using `stty`:

```
$ stty columns 80
$ vim path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to immae I also have a solution using `tmux`:

```
tmux -L $(date +%s) unbind-key -a \; set -g mouse off \; set -g status off \; new-session sleep 36500d \; split-window -h -l 80 -b bash -c 'vim "$@"; tmux kill-server' bash "$@"
```

Note that this assumes your editing session lasts less than 36500 days. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42901) for alternatives to the use of `sleep`